# Application crashing on video gallery picker in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

My flutter version is 3.13.2 and I am using [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) 1.0.4.

While picking a video from the iOS gallery, it picks the video first time without any crash, but the second time it always crashes. It's not crashing on an Android device and while picking images it's not crashing either. It always crashes the second time I pick a video from the gallery.

Here is the crash log I receive from the Firebase crashlytics :

> Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a
> background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread

```
TextButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
    final XFile? galleryVideo =
        await picker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  },
  child: Text("Pick video from gallery"),
),
```

I already tried updating the Flutter version to the latest and the library version to the latest one.

Answer (score 1):

I tried & tested the below-mentioned code in the iOS simulator. It's working as expected. You should try & test and provide me with an acknowledgement. You can ask anything in the comment section.

Add these codes in the `Info.plist` file:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>
    
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the camera.</string>

<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app does not require access to the microphone.</string>
```

Copy & paste these codes in the `main.dart` file:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:image_picker/image_picker.dart";

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Flutter Demo",
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: openVideoPicker,
          child: const Text("Pick Video From Gallery"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> openVideoPicker() async {
    XFile xFile = XFile("");
    xFile = await picker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery) ?? XFile("");
    xFile.path.isEmpty ? print("Picker Close") : print("Picked: ${xFile.path}");
    return Future<void>.value();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with flutter 3.13.2. After switching off impeller it works.

Switching off impeller: Add the following tags under the top-level <dict> tag in your app’s Info.plist file.

<key>FLTEnableImpeller</key>
<false/>

Answer (score 0):

Updating flutter to 3.13.3 and [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) to 1.0.4 fixed the issue.